# Loading a certain legitimate website causes my Mac to crash

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, crash, firefox

Opening the oneplus 3 website ([specifically this page](https://oneplus.net/3)) causes my MBP (mid-2009) to crash regardless of the browser -- I've tried it with the same results on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. It loads and displays correctly, then after a minute or so the computer stops responding, only the mouse can be moved occasionally but nothing can be clicked, and none of the keyboard shortcuts work so only a hard reset helps. I've done it multiple times with the same results, monitoring temperature sensors (nothing overheats) and CPU load (no abnormal spikes). I'm running a reasonably fresh install of El Capitan 10.11.5 and this is the only website I've found that does this. Is anyone else having problems with this site?

Edit: I've attached the pertinent part from the Console log below, it looks like a graphics card bug:

```
26/06/16 20:18:43,680   Brave Helper[1201]  Couldn't set selectedTextBackgroundColor from default ()
26/06/16 20:18:48,888   Brave Helper[1206]  CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(Video): Channel exception! exception type = 0x23 = Video Engine Error (MSPDEC Error)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(OpenGL): Channel exception! exception type = 0xd = Graphics Engine Error (GR Error 5)
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   IOVendorGLContext::ReportGPURestart 
26/06/16 20:18:56,000   kernel[0]   NVDA(OpenGL): Channel exception! exception type = 0x9 = Graphics Engine Error (GR Error 1)
```

Comment: Seems that it's resolved on Sierra. Can You please attach crash file?

Comment: Works okay for me running 10.11.5 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

Comment: Do you use any plugins with your browsers?

Comment: Try opening it up with the Brave Browser: https://brave.com/. It blocks trackers, ads, and other potentially malicious content and could resolve your issue.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I've edited in the console log output at the moment of the crash, is this it or do you need something else?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan I use plenty of plugins in Chrome, only a few in Firefox and none in Safari and Brave. I don't think a plugin is causing this.

Comment: @JohnRamos I've tried the Brave browser, unfortunately the result is exactly the same as the other browsers.

Comment: I tested this on a MBP mid-2009 and had no problem.  Have you tried running [Apple Hardware Test(AHT)?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to see if there is a problem with your graphics chip?  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with AC adapter attached.  Let us know the result.

Comment: @pogonomyrmex So it's probably a legitimate part of the site. And indeed it looks to my amateur eyes like a graphics issue. Try what Allan said.